# Surround with - multiple selections

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I currently have to surround some scriptlets in a lot of `jsp` pages with a custom tag. The first jsp took me over an hour and there's a lot more to go. I made a [live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-templates.html) for the custom tag.
The technique I'm currently using is just searching for `<%` and surround scriptlet by scriptlet with this tag using the `CTRL-ALT-T` shortcut.

Now since I can't find anything on jetbrains about this, does anyone know of a better, faster technique to just wrap every occurence of a scriptlet within a given `jsp` page with my tag? This would make my work 10 times faster.

I don't have to replace every single scriptlet so a replace-all wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/structural-search-and-replace.html) might be helpful.